# html5 search input events

Tags: html, dom, search, dom-events

What event is triggered when a user clicks the <kbd>X</kbd> in a search input field (in webkit browsers) to cancel the search or clear the text?

Information is available about [restyling the button](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/) and [other custom events](http://ajaxian.com/archives/searching-for-the-html5-search-input), but not on using this button.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The onsearch event is triggered both when the search input is submitted and when the user clears the search.

```
<input type=search onsearch="javascript:alert('SEARCH: ' + this.value);" />
```

Comment: This event does not seem to trigger in IE when the user clears the search.